# Having trouble with creating custom user in Django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I am trying to create a custom user. However, I noticed my data is just inserting the raw data to database from my POST request. 
For example, if I insert my data from the terminal using create superuser, my data in my database looks something like this

```
id | password                                                                       | last_login | email                                                                                | staff | adm
 1 | pbkdf2_sha256$180000$bGUp7u590CDf$wlecM+W0h7/6q/rZhKP73IMH13msn87I/RoK/VJewKk= | NULL       | <bound method BaseUserManager.normalize_email of <class 'qssgg.models.UserManager'>> |     1 |     1 |
```

However, if I try to store data from my REST API POST request, it stores data like this

```
| id | password | last_login | email                 | staff | admin |
+----+----------+------------+-----------------------+-------+-------+
|  1 | hi       | NULL       | bobby000000@gmail.com |     0 |     0 |
```

As you can see, the password is not getting encrypted and email is different. I am wondering why this is happening? I am following a tutorial and here is my code:

models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password = None, isStaff=False, isAdmin=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("User must add password")
        userObj = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email
        )
        userObj.set_password(password)
        userObj.staff = isStaff
        userObj.admin = isAdmin
        userObj.save(using=self._db)
        return userObj

    def create_staffuser(self, email, password = None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password = password,
            isStaff = True
        )
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password = None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password = password,
            isStaff = True,
            isAdmin= True,
        )
        return user



class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 255, unique = True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def isStaff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def isAdmin(self):
        return self.admin
```

ursl.py

```
from .views import UserViewSet
router.register('api/registerUser', UserViewSet, 'registerUsers')
```

seralizer.py

```
# qssgg Seralizer
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

And my request is `http://localhost:8000/api/registerUsers/`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are two separate problems.

First, your call to `self.normalize_email` is missing the parentheses, so the function doesn't get executed. Change it to the following:

```
email = self.normalize_email
```

Second, Django REST Framework is not calling your `create_user` function which correctly uses `set_password()` to set the user password. Add the following method your `serializers.py`:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    return User.objects.create_user(validated_data)
```